# Returning all values from E column using Range function

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Main()

    Dim sheet As Worksheet

    Range("A5:E273").Select

    'I want to dynamically get all the columns instead of hard-coding to
    'E273, say there are 400 and might increase later. 

    Range(sheet).Select

End
```

Comment: I want to get entire E column in selection. Help is much appreciated. I am a noob btw.

Comment: I see you got far with your code.

Comment: huh, any help? Guru?

Comment: Using Last poperty helped but I want to use a standard code. What I did is
Range("A5:E273" & last).Select

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have two conflicting questions:

> *"I want to dynamically get all the columns..."*

Which doesn't mean what I believe this statement to mean:

> *"E273, say there are 400 and might increase later"*

So your first point you are requesting to get all the columns... The second point appears that you are referring to rows. I am going to take an educated guess and assume your intent is rows because of the remaining *(very)* minimal code provided (`A5:E273`).

You can easily grab the last row in any column with this function:

```
Function LastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal col As Variant = 1) As Long
    With ws
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

I recommend against using variables that are also named objects within Excel, which in your case your declaration of `sheet`. If you were to type `Sheet` into VBE and press <kbd>F1</kbd>, you would see that it's a semi-reserved property name:

> Returns the sheet name for the specified PublishObject object. Read-only String.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> *expression*.Sheet
>
> *expression*   A variable that represents a **PublishObject** object.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> This example determines the name of the worksheet that contains the first **PublishObject** object that is saved as static HTML in the Web page. The example then sets the **Boolean** variable blnSheetFound to **True**. If no items in the document have been saved as static HTML, blnSheetFound is **False**.

Instead, you should consider a different variable, such as `ws` for example.

So, your final outcome would look like:

```
Option Explicit

Function LastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal col As Variant = 1) As Long
    With ws
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

Sub Main()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, myRng As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set myRng = ws.Range("A5:E" & LastRow(ws))

    myRng.Select

End
```